# Перейти ниже рисунка после float

Tags: html, css

Помогите разобраться.

Необходимо перенести текст ниже рисунка:

```html
<div id="news">
<img src="http://img.tyt.by/p/0e/f/1_stepway_version3.jpg" 
 style="float:left; height:350px; width:458px">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
    Etiam ac convallis diam, in dapibusllus erat. Sed eget enim 
    facilisis mauris teget pretium ultricies. Morbi eu tincidunt augue.
</div>
<br />
ТЕКСТ НУЖЕН НИЖЕ МАШИНЫ
```

Comment: Можно взять текст вот в такой блок: `<div style="clear:both">`

Comment: советую почитать материал в интернете о том, какие ошибки могут возникать при использовании float и как делать очистку его свойств. В принципе Вам ниже, всё верно ответили, но всё же советую разобраться, иначе вся вёрстка будет плавать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно сразу после картинки с float отменить "плавающий" эффект. Для этого следующему элементу присвоить стиль `clear: left;` (или в более общем случае `clear: both;`.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<div id="news"><img src="http://img.tyt.by/p/0e/f/1_stepway_version3.jpg" style="float:none; height:350px; width:458px"><br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac convallis diam, in dapibusllus erat. Sed eget enim facilisis mauris teget pretium ultricies. Morbi eu tincidunt augue.
</div><br />
ТЕКСТ НУЖЕН НИЖЕ МАШИНЫ
```

Если нужно чтобы текст был под рисунком, тогда зачем задаете float:left??? Выше код как и просили, текст снизу! float:none - отменяет оптекание слева... также добавил 
 чтобы текст начался с новой строки

Answer (score 4):

можно добавить `overflow:hidden` у контейнера `news`

```css
#news {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <img src="http://img.tyt.by/p/0e/f/1_stepway_version3.jpg" style="float:left; height:350px; width:458px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac convallis diam, in dapibusllus erat. Sed eget enim facilisis mauris teget pretium ultricies. Morbi eu tincidunt augue.
</div>
<br />ТЕКСТ НУЖЕН НИЖЕ МАШИНЫ
```

Answer (score 3):

В том-то и дело, что `float:` задает обтекание.
В общем случае для картинки совсем не обязательно в данном случае использовать `float: left`. Все картинки по умолчанию ставятся слева (если до этого не был изменен родительский блок на, скажем, `text-align: right`). Другое дело, что этого может требовать конкретная задача.

В вашем случае для элемента, который содержит в себе текст нужно добавить `clear: both` (both - для надежности).

В данном случае вы делаете двойную работу: сначала просите, чтобы текст картинку обтекал (`float: left`), а затем просите, чтобы не обтекал (`clear: both`). Этого делать не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так это делают в Bootstrap 3-й версии. @toxxxa предложил почти то же самое, но зачем делать это для следующего элемента? Ведь есть псевдоэлемент `:after`

```css
#news:before,
#news:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
#news:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">
  <img src="http://img.tyt.by/p/0e/f/1_stepway_version3.jpg" style="float:left; height:350px; width:458px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac convallis diam, in dapibusllus erat. Sed eget enim facilisis mauris teget pretium ultricies. Morbi eu tincidunt augue.
</div>
<br />ТЕКСТ НУЖЕН НИЖЕ МАШИНЫ
```